# VBA Run Loop until have X examples in MsgBox

Tags: vba, loops, msgbox

Today I am trying to run basic loop using "for". I would like to run a loop till I get 20 random numbers between 26 - 28 in MsgBox.

```
Sub C7()

    Dim b As Integer
    Dim f As Single
    Dim ret As String

    For b = 1 To 20
        f = Rnd() * 28
        If f >= 26 And f <= 28 Then
        ret = ret & Str(f)

        End If
    Next b

        MsgBox ret

End Sub
```

Following code runs the loop 20-times and gives me all values between 26 - 28 (usually not more than 3). What I need is a code which will run the loop X-times until it gives me 20 numbers between 26 - 27.

Every advice is welcome! Thanks

Comment: Just use `Rnd() + 26`.

Comment: To get the 20 numbers, add an else statement after `ret = ret & Str(f) else b = b -1 `

Comment: Thanks Comintern, this actually solved it. But what if I need to generate numbers from 26 - 30 ? Or even 26,4 | 28,1 | 27,3 etc? I will edit my question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the randomize to give a number less than 3, then add 26.

Rnd() returns a number between [0, 1), multiplying that by 28 will never result in 28.  And frequently will result in a number below 28, which gets avoided in the output because of your if block.

`f = (Rnd() * 3)`  will give a random number between [0, 3).

`f = ((Rnd() * 3) + 26)` will give a random number between [26, 29).

Comment: Upvote for most efficient solution. However, I included a generic answer for "run loop X times until something happens" that OP should check.

Comment: Thank you sir! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a `Do-Loop Until` or `Do While-Loop` loop. This kind of loop runs until a condition is met. In your case, that condition would be "20 messages are printed".

The `Do While-Loop` loop checks the condition at the start, so if the condition is `False` at first, the loop wont run.

The `Do-Loop Until` loop checks the condition at the end, so the loop will run at least once.

An example code following your previous `For` loop:

```
Sub C7()

Dim b As Integer
Dim f As Single
Dim ret As String
dim count as Integer: count = 0

Do
    f = Rnd() * 28
    If f >= 26 And f <= 28 Then
        ret = ret & Str(f)
        count = count + 1
    End If
Loop until count = 20

    MsgBox ret

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nicholas,
Currently I am practising "For" but "Do-Loop Until" will be very useful for my next tasks. Thank you very much!